# Return ticket...but not using departure element

Tags: air-travel

We are traveling Thailand to collect our 14yo Daughter, is it possible to buy 3 return tickets but for one of the tickets (Daughters) only use the return part?

Will the fact that she is not on the UK departure cause a problem, and affect the return journey back from Thailand?

The main issue is that we cannot book a single return for a minor to join us on our return flights, and don't really like the idea of paying a minimum 3 one way journeys on top of a return flight for one.

Any help on this or direction to someone that may know more would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, no. When your daughter doesn't show up for the flight from the UK to Thailand, the airline will cancel her whole booking.

It might be worth calling the airline's customer service number or a travel agent to see if they can help you. The website might not sell you the ticket you want, but an actual human being may be able to be more flexible.

Comment: Or, use a travel agent. This is the sort of thing they are good at, and useful for. Besides, they might be able to find a better fare than just looking at one airline.

Comment: Ok, thank you both for the comments. I think you are both right and I shall give a couple of airlines and travel agents a call tomorrow. They are obviously the people to speak to......cheers

Comment: @GregHewgill Good point -- I added that to the answer.